# Can't import named exports from an external NPM library with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, import, export, next.js, dynamic-loading

I'm unable to import named exports from an external component library I've created as it is described in the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import). The situation seems to be very niche as I struggle to find anything online that would bring me closer to the solution. Did anyone manage to get it to work?

Here comes the context...

### In my NPM library

#### Component

**Modal component** (fragment)

```
const Modal: React.FC<ModalProps> = ({ onCancelCallback, children }) => {...};
export default Modal;
```

As you can see, I export it as a default from Modal.tsx but later re-export it as a named export in every folder's index.ts file like so:

```
export { default as Modal } from './Modal';
```

then

```
export { Modal } from './Modal';
```

and, finally:

```
export * from './components';
```

#### Interface

**ModalProps**

```
export interface ModalProps {
  onCancelCallback?: () => void;
}
```

### In Next.js

Here's how I'm importing my external "Modal" component in one of the Next.js components (not pages):

**nextjscomponent.tsx**

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const Modal = dynamic(() => import('my-ui-kit').then((mod) => mod.Modal), {
  ssr: false,
});
```

**TypeScript error**

```sh
Argument of type '() => Promise<React.ComponentClass<never, any> | React.FunctionComponent<never> | { default: React.ComponentType<never>; } | React.FC<ModalProps>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DynamicOptions<{}> | (() => LoaderComponent<{}>) | LoaderComponent<{}>'.
  Type '() => Promise<React.ComponentClass<never, any> | React.FunctionComponent<never> | { default: React.ComponentType<never>; } | React.FC<ModalProps>>' is not assignable to type '() => LoaderComponent<{}>'.
    Type 'Promise<ComponentClass<never, any> | FunctionComponent<never> | { default: ComponentType<never>; } | FC<ModalProps>>' is not assignable to type 'LoaderComponent<{}>'.
      Type 'ComponentClass<never, any> | FunctionComponent<never> | { default: ComponentType<never>; } | FC<ModalProps>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<{}, any> | FunctionComponent<{}> | { default: ComponentType<{}>; }'.
        Type 'ComponentClass<never, any>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<{}, any> | FunctionComponent<{}> | { default: ComponentType<{}>; }'.
          Type 'ComponentClass<never, any>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<{}, any>'.
            Types of property 'getDerivedStateFromProps' are incompatible.
              Type 'GetDerivedStateFromProps<never, any> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'GetDerivedStateFromProps<{}, any> | undefined'.
                Type 'GetDerivedStateFromProps<never, any>' is not assignable to type 'GetDerivedStateFromProps<{}, any>'.
                  Types of parameters 'nextProps' and 'nextProps' are incompatible.
                    Type 'Readonly<{}>' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)
```

### Notes

- I'm using Rollup to transpile the contents of "src" folder with component and index files into "dist" folder which ends up with index.cjs.js (for CommonJS), index.esm.js (for ES modules) and a bunch of automatically generated .d.ts files.
- I'm using Yarn link to test the integration of my external library into my Next.js project locally.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

---

### Update Apr. 4, 2020

On the official GitHub page of Next.js I was told that the issue might have been related to the fact that two @types/react libraries were co-living in the same Next.js project.

Here's what I tried (to no avail) to test this hypothesis:

---

I rand a quick "yarn why @types/react" and saw the following:

```sh
yarn why v1.22.4
[1/4]   Why do we have the module "@types/react"...?
[2/4]   Initialising dependency graph...
[3/4]   Finding dependency...
[4/4]   Calculating file sizes...
=> Found "@types/react@16.9.32"
info Has been hoisted to "@types/react"
info This module exists because it's specified in "devDependencies".
info Disk size without dependencies: "164KB"
info Disk size with unique dependencies: "1.98MB"
info Disk size with transitive dependencies: "1.98MB"
info Number of shared dependencies: 2
=> Found "@types/react-dom#@types/react@16.9.31"
info This module exists because "@types#react-dom" depends on it.
info Disk size without dependencies: "164KB"
info Disk size with unique dependencies: "1.98MB"
info Disk size with transitive dependencies: "1.98MB"
info Number of shared dependencies: 2
✨  Done in 0.99s.
```

I then tried three things:

1. Unlink my library > yarn cache clean > reinstall the library (this time from a freshly generated tgz tarball). The issue persisted
2. Yarn remove @types/react from the Next.js folder (effectively leaving only @types/react v16.9.31 hoisted from @types/react-dom). The issue persisted
3. Completely removed node_modules and yarn.lock and reinstalled all packages (including my library from the tarball). The issue persisted.

I'm still seing the same error message.

By the way, that same component works fine with dynamic loading when imported from Next.js project's own components folder but the goal is to use the external UI kit, obviously.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the solution that came from Next.js's GitHub by @r0skar:

---

I've done the following:

**In my external ui kit**

```
export type { ModalProps } from './Modal.interface';
```

**In Next.js**

```
import { ModalProps } from 'my-ui-kit';
const Modal = dynamic<ModalProps>(() => import('my-ui-kit').then((mod) => mod.Modal), {
  ssr: false,
});
```

This made TypeScript (and myself) happy.

Answer (score 0):

Using `async` functions also worked for me. So, your case would look like this, I think

```
const Modal = dynamic(
  async () => (await import('my-ui-kit')).Modal,
  { ssr: false }
);
```